# Python 2.7 substitute subprocess with subprocess32

Tags: debian, python

In the Python subprocess [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) it has been encouraged to substitute the default python2.7 subprocess module with subprocess32. How should I do that? 
Please give a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are working in a python `virtualenv` (as you should be doing), you can do:

```
pip install subprocess32
```

in the activated virtualen.

You can also install this as a [package](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/python-subprocess32):

```
apt-get install -y python-subprocess32
```

But that doesn't get you the added functionality in any program running in a virtualenv, and since you should not use `pip` installs on the system Python, you are limited (i.e. you should limit yourself to) in your python program to python modules available via `apt-get`.